# How to resize the uitableviewcell accessory buttons

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to ask whether it is possible to resize the accessory buttons of a `UITableViewCell`. Also I want to resize the buttons in edit mode. For example in normal mode, I want a bigger detail disclosure button, and in edit mode I want a bigger delete button and bigger red minus button. I have this issue because I want to use it on the iPad, which has a bigger screen than the iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify the existing edit buttons, but you can provide your own with the [accessoryView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/accessoryView) and [editingAccessoryView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/editingAccessoryView) properties on `UITableViewCell`. These let you change the view displayed on the right-hand side of the cell.

To change the view on the left you need to have a custom cell and override `setEditing:` to insert/animate-in your own custom view.